# React Native: Displaying multiple images through map

Tags: react-native, mapping, react-native-flatlist, react-props

I have an object which I passed through another route and I want to display the images it holds. I am checking if I received the props like this:

```
  checkParams = () => {
    let params = this.props.navigation.state.params;
    console.log("comments.js params= ", params);

    if (params.photoId) {

      this.setState({
        photoId: params.photoId,
        REAL: params.REAL,
        FAKE: params.FAKE,
        url: params.url,
        author: params.author,
        posted: params.posted,
        caption: params.caption
      });

      this.fetchComments(params.photoId);
    }
  };
```

console.log("comments.js params= ", params) gives:

```
comments.js params=  Object {
  "FAKE": 0,
  "REAL": 0,
  "author": "USER",
  "caption": "CAPTION",
  "photoId": "47d5-9420-c99a-7459-640d",
  "posted": "72 minutes ago",
  "url": Array [
    Object {
      "url": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/...someURL...",
    },
    Object {
      "url": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/...someURL...",
    },
    Object {
      "url": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/...someURL...",
    },
    Object {
      "url": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/...someURL...",
    },
  ],
}
```

To display all the "url", I am doing this:

```
          {
            (this.state.url).map(photoItem => (
              <Image 
                source={{ uri: photoItem.url }}
              />
            ))
          }
```

However, I keep getting this Error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.url.map)
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **this.state.url**:

```
{
  "FAKE": 0,
  "REAL": 0,
  "author": "USER",
  "caption": "CAPTION",
  "photoId": "47d5-9420-c99a-7459-640d",
  "posted": "72 minutes ago",
  "url": [
    {
      "url": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/...someURL...",
    },
    {
      "url": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/...someURL...",
    },
    {
      "url": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/...someURL...",
    },
    {
      "url": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/...someURL...",
    },
  ],
}
```

you can do:

```js
<View>
  {this.state.url.map((img, index) => {
    return <Image source={{uri: img.url }} key={index} style={imgStyle}/>;
  })}
<View/>
```

Demo: https://snack.expo.io/@abranhe/images-mapping

[image]

**App.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';
import data from './data';

export default () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {data.url.map((image, index) => {
        return <Image source={{ uri: image.url }} style={styles.image} />;
      })}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  image: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  },
});
```

**data.js**

```js
export default {
  FAKE: 0,
  REAL: 0,
  author: 'USER',
  caption: 'CAPTION',
  photoId: '47d5-9420-c99a-7459-640d',
  posted: '72 minutes ago',
  url: [
    {
      url:
        'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/13/05/15/puppy-1903313__340.jpg',
    },
    {
      url:
        'https://images.pexels.com/photos/1108099/pexels-photo-1108099.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500',
    },
    {
      url:
        'https://3c1703fe8d.site.internapcdn.net/newman/gfx/news/hires/2018/2-dog.jpg',
    },
    {
      url: 'https://www.guidedogs.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Mobile.jpg',
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: Hi, I am still getting TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.url.map). Is it because maybe the URL is undefined during render?

Comment: If so you can use get from lodash `_.get(this.state, 'url', [])`

Comment: Hi, how and where would I use loadash? Do I need to install a dependency? Do I put it in componnetDidMount?

Comment: Hi, I have imported it, but where should I use it? I have used it in render, componentDidMount, but it is still saying URL is undefined.

Comment: @KartikeyaSharma where you mapping your images, let say the images are at `this.state.url` then where you are using `this.state.url.map(i => ...)` replace it by  `_.get(this.state, 'url', []).map(i => ...)`, so instead the url being undefined it will be an empty array

Comment: thank you. It is not giving an error now. However, it is also not showing the image on the screen. The View where the image should load is empty. It is displaying the URL in console.log though.